# Bower config override setting ignored

Tags: bower

I have created a `.bowercc` file with the following setting:

```
{
   "directory" : "./src/libs/bower_components"
}
```

My `.bowercc` file is installed in the projects root... folders/files are:

```
node_modules
src
src/libs
src/libs/bower_components
bower.json
.bowercc
```

No matter what I do, every time I define a dependency, bower creates a `bower_components` folder at the root level, and installs the component there, instead of in `src/libs/bower_components`.  According to the bower docs, just having a `.bowercc` file at the root should overribe the global config.  What am I doing wrong?

I've tried:

- "directory" : "./src/libs/bower_components"
- "directory" : "/src/libs/bower_components"
- "directory" : "src/libs/bower_components"

I've also tried adding the directory setting to the bower.json file.

Github: https://github.com/LongLiveCHIEF/rookie-tracker/

Comment: How are you defining dependencies? Is your bower up to date?

Comment: yeah, used npm to install it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rename the config file to .bowerrc. ".bowercc" is incorrect.

Comment: (sigh)... thank you. Dislexia can strike at any time it would appear.

Comment: Haha I did the same exact thing. DERP!